# Unable to create optional arguments with dotnet core in C#

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core

I'm trying to specify an optional argument on a dotnet core library running on ubuntu. (version - 1.0.0-preview2-003121)

I add the signature as so:

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string cmd, int sqlCommandTimeout = 30){
}
```

I can compile and run the project no problem, but I have to call the function with both parameters.

If I try to call the function with cmd only and I get a compile error:

```
dataLink.ExecuteNonQuery(qry)
```

Error:

error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'commandTimeOut' of 'X.ExecuteNonQuery(string, int)'

Are optional parameters not supported in dotnet core or am I doing it wrong? Thanks

Update:
Optional parameters are supported and working - the issue was because I was calling the class through an interface. Thanks for the help

Comment: I think we need more to be able to find the solution. Can you post more relevant code?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid looks like a complete example to me

Comment: @ardila well if the user is experiencing issues with his code, and from what I can see, I don't see any errors.. so the problem isn't within the 2 lines of code the OP provided

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid did you run the code on .net core on Ubuntu, or a regular .net app on Windows?

Comment: @ardila I haven't ran it using .net core on Ubuntu but I am answering the part of the question where OP asks *or am I doing it wrong?*, also along with doing research to see if there is any documentation on this or if anyone else has posted similar experiences.. and I can't find any.. plus Pablo's answer's says that he/she doesn't encounter any issues with optional parameters

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid right, I didn't get an error on Windows either, but until we've verified / reproduced on the environment in the question, I don't see how more code is the next logical step. Plus, "please post more code" is not exactly an answer to "or am I doing it wrong", is it?

Comment: In your example, the parameter is named `sqlCommandTimeout` in the signature, but `commandTimeOut` in the error message. Are you sure you are invoking the method you think you are invoking? E.g. if the method is in another assembly, is the compiled assembly up-to-date and matching the source code version? And is your object `dataLink` of the type you think it is?

Comment: @ardila well I wouldn't have suggested to add more code if the OP was in fact doing it wrong or a piece of the provided code was wrong.  So asking to post more code is indirectly saying that the OP is not doing it wrong, or else I would assume there would be more answers and/or comments that would be more relevant to helping the OP with his issue, rather than trying to correct someone who is only trying to help.

Comment: - arrg - sorry dumb question. I was calling the class through an interface - didn't realise until @Dirk Vollmar pointed out the signature was different.

Comment: @onemorecupofcoffee: Feel free to delete your question to indicate that it no longer needs attention.

Comment: Sorry, accepted the answer because there is no issue and I can't delete - I'll just update the question to be more informative

Comment: Stop using the term DNX which is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using .Net Core (Windows) and I definitely do not encounter any issues with optional parameters. Bear in mind that optional parameters are a feature of the language, not of the framework.

Are you getting that error at runtime?

Its not ideal but if you only have those two parameters and only the last one is optional you might consider just creating an overload?

Comment: - arrg - sorry dumb question. I was calling the class through an interface - didn't realise until @Dirk Vollmar pointed out the signature was different.